# Orthogonal regression fitting in Java / Convex Conjugate / Optimisation

Tags: java, optimization

Would someone has an example of how to implement an orthogonal regression fitting in Java ([Total Least Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares)) or how to find the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) for a set of data ? My aim is to find the [support function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) that will best act as a lower bound for the data.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions that ask for a library aren't a good fit for this site, because they get stale very quickly. It would make a fine question if you yourself attempted to find a function and got stuck somewhere, seeking help with specific problem.

Comment: I understand... So how should I formulate my problem ? because I don't really know where to begin with this. Thanks